# Javascript onclick with onmouseover and onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have an image with a few javascript calls on it, most of which work OK.

Basically, what I want it to do, is when clicked swap image and then depending on which image it is currently on, to swap on mouseover too.

Here's my HTML:

```
<a href="#show" class="show_hide">
<img src="<?php echo WEB_URL; ?>/images/show-more-arrow.jpg" width="61" height="45" id="clicktoggleimage" onclick="changeImage()" onMouseOver="checkMouseOver()" onMouseOut="checkMouseOut()" /></a>
```

And my Javascript:

```
function changeImage() {
    if (document.getElementById("clicktoggleimage").src == "http://www.pete.com/images/show-less-arrow.jpg") {
        document.getElementById("clicktoggleimage").src = "http://www.pete.com/images/show-more-arrow.jpg";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("clicktoggleimage").src = "http://www.pete.com/images/show-less-arrow.jpg";
    }
}

function checkMouseOver() {
    if (document.getElementById("clicktoggleimage").src == "http://www.pete.com/images/show-less-arrow.jpg") {
        document.getElementById("clicktoggleimage").src = "http://www.pete.com/images/show-less-arrow-over.jpg";
    } else if (document.getElementById("clicktoggleimage").src == "http://www.pete.com/images/show-more-arrow.jpg") {
        document.getElementById("clicktoggleimage").src = "http://www.pete.com/images/show-more-arrow-over.jpg";    
    }
}

function checkMouseOut() {
    if (document.getElementById("clicktoggleimage").src == "http://www.pete.com/images/show-less-arrow-over.jpg") {
        document.getElementById("clicktoggleimage").src = "http://www.pete.com/images/show-less-arrow.jpg";
    } else if (document.getElementById("clicktoggleimage").src == "http://www.pete.com/images/show-more-arrow-over.jpg") {
        document.getElementById("clicktoggleimage").src = "http://www.pete.com/images/show-more-arrow.jpg"; 
    }
}
```

This works fine, except when the button is clicked for the second time, the image doesn't revert back to the show-less-arrow.jpg

Many thanks for your help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3gQEG/ 
replace the url's with working images and i'll have another look :p I don't get wht you're trying to accomplish to be honest.

Comment: Basically, the image needs to have a swap on hover and when clicked change to a different image. The reason is, because it slides down a separate div when it is clicked. Hence the show more or less buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this JS a lot more efficient.

Since it appears you're only replacing `'more'` with `'less'` and vice versa, in your `changeImage` function, that is exactly what your function should do. The mouse over/off is only toggling the `'-over'` section of your string.

So, remove the event listeners from your HTML:

```
<a href="#show" class="show_hide">
    <img src="<?php echo WEB_URL; ?>/images/show-more-arrow.jpg" width="61" height="45" id="clicktoggleimage" />
</a>
```

And use this Javascript:

```
var img = document.getElementById("clicktoggleimage");

function changeImage() {
    if (img.src.indexOf('less') == -1) {
        img.src = img.src.replace('more', 'less');
    } else {
        img.src = img.src.replace('less', 'more');
    }
}

function hoverImage() {
    if (img.src.indexOf('arrow-over') == -1) {
        img.src = img.src.replace('arrow', 'arrow-over');
    } else {
        img.src = img.src.replace('arrow-over', 'arrow');
    }
}

img.onclick = cangeImage;
img.onmouseover = img.onmouseout = hoverImage;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but nothing works when I try this? There's no activity on the image for mouse over or click?

Comment: Can you `console.log(img.src)` at the start and end of the functions, and see what the result is?